# Попарное перемножение элементов списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Как перемножить парные элементы в списке?

Например, есть список:

```
list1 = ['1','1000','2','1500','1.32','1100']
```

На выходе нужно получить список:

```
list1 = ['1000','3000','1452']
```

Нужна функция которая преобразует так список. Возможно через лямдбу как-то?

Comment: Можно через reduce

Comment: Можно подробнее расписать, пожалуйста? Я только начинаю в python, понимаю что нужно еще через float преобразовать строки в числа, но пока к готовому результату прийти не могу

Comment: Если не решать задачи самостоятельно, то вы так и не « начнёте» в Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое решение - сделать как-то так:

```
list1 = [x * y for x, y in zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2])]
```

Функция `zip()` группирует последовательные элементы списка, после чего мы их преобразовываем в новый список при помощи генератора списков ([list comprehenshions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)), с элементами, получаемыми перемножением чисел в каждой паре.

Но, так как у вас в списке находятся не числа, а строки, их еще предварительно нужно преобразовать в числовой тип, для чисел с плавающей точкой используется тип `float`.

```
list1 = ['1','1000','2','1500','1.32','1100']
list1 = [x * y for x, y in zip(*[map(float, list1)] * 2)]
print(list1)
```

Получаем результат:

```
[1000.0, 3000.0, 1452.0]
```

В данном случае дробную часть можно отбросить, но, так как при перемножении чисел с плавающей точкой числа не всегда будут получаться целыми - я не стал этого делать.

Также, обратите внимание, что если в исходном списке будет содержаться значение, которое нельзя сконвертировать в число, то будет выведена ошибка, этот метод рабочий если вам заранее достоверно известно, что список состоит только из чисел.

Comment: Дополню, что можно сразу сделать `[float(x) * float(y) for x, y in zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2])]`. Тогда он будет переводить в float сразу перед перемножением.

Comment: @mironovmeow соглашусь, так будет попроще, спасибо!

Comment: можно сделать так: `[x*y for x, y in  zip(*[map(float, list1)] * 2)]`

Comment: @Danis о, это красивое решение!

Answer (score 0):

Про старый добрый `range` никто не вспомнил ))

```py
list1 = ['1', '1000', '2', '1500', '1.32', '1100']

list1 = [float(list1[i]) * float(list1[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)]
print(list1)
```

Результат:

```
[1000.0, 3000.0, 1452.0]
```